# Query didn't gave me the expected result

Tags: mysql, sql

ap table

```
id  tid     code    pid      cl           date  
1   1       1002    17      DC      2011-04-05 16:14:37     
2   1       1002    18      DC      2011-04-05 16:14:37     
3   1       1002    19      DC      2011-04-05 16:14:37     
4   2       1002    12      SC      2011-04-05 16:15:59     
5   2       1002    9       SC      2011-04-05 16:15:59     
6   2       1002    21      SC      2011-04-05 16:15:59     
7   3       1003    20      DC      2011-04-07 14:57:40     
8   3       1003    12      DC      2011-04-07 14:57:40     
9   3       1003    9       DC      2011-04-07 14:57:40     
10  3       1003    21      DC      2011-04-07 14:57:40     
11  4       1002    18      SC      2011-04-08 18:10:04     
12  4       1002    19      SC      2011-04-08 18:10:04     
13  4       1002    22      SC      2011-04-08 18:10:04     
14  5       1001    17      SC      2011-04-08 18:21:10
```

at table

```
   tid  totalamount     code    pstatus     cdate   
    1   65.98           1002        R       2011-04-05 16:14:37 
    2   17.74           1002        R       2011-04-05 16:15:59     
    3   96.36           1003        R       2011-04-07 14:57:40     
    4   25.94           1002        S       2011-04-08 18:10:04     
    5   9               1001        R       2011-05-08 18:21:10
```

i tried like this but its not correct

```
SELECT at.totalamount, at.pstatus, ap.cl
FROM `at` AS at
INNER JOIN ap AS ap ON at.`code` = ap.`code`
WHERE ap.cl = 'SC'
AND at.`code` = '1002'
GROUP BY at.`code`
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

I expected Result

```
   pstatus->S    pstatus->R


code    Stotalamount   Rtotalamount   Sstatus    Rstatus  cl
1002    25.94          17.74          S          R        SC
```

Please any body tell me the correct query

Comment: This makes no sense the example query you gave us has 3 columns but you want the results to have 5 columns.  What were your actual results and what do you expect?

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a site that is intended to 'tell' you the code for a problem. Please stop asking similar questions like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want to add the `totalamount` twice, once for the the `R` status and another for the `S` status.

But I don't understand how you are joining the `ap` table and why the `65.98` is not added. Should the join be done on the date columns as well?

This may work but you have to test it with different data to be sure. Or explain more of what the columns in the two tables represent and what you want the query to show.

```
SELECT at.code
     , SUM(IF(at.pstatus='S', at.totalamount, 0))
       AS Stotalamount
     , SUM(IF(at.pstatus='R', at.totalamount, 0))
       AS Rtotalamount
FROM at
WHERE EXISTS 
  ( SELECT 1
    FROM ap
    WHERE at.code = ap.code
      AND at.cdate = ap.date
      AND ap.cl = 'SC'
  )
  AND at.code = 1002
GROUP BY at.code
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: I need including DC-Stotalamount DC-Ctotalamount and (DC-Stotalamount+DC-Ctotalamount)as DC-Total also Please send the query for this output

Comment: @user36 - I think [Rent a Coder](http://www.rent-acoder.com/) is a site that would better suit your needs.  Stack Overflow is not a place where code is vomited up on demand.  You have to give some evidence that you've actually put forth some effort.